# Grant Azure Function in staging slot MSI access to the SQL Server Database

Tags: sql-server, azure-managed-identity, azure-deployment-slots

I have an Azure Function (function-name) for which I granted MSI access to the SQL Server Database using the following sql query:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = N'function-name')
BEGIN
 CREATE USER [function-name] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
 ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [function-name];
END
```

I added a staging deployment slot. How do I grant function-name in staging slot MSI access to the SQL Server Database?

Comment: something like `CREATE USER [function-name/staging] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;` should work.

Comment: You also need to enable managed identity on the slot.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it worked like this:

```
CREATE USER [function-name/slots/staging] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER
```